# Can't run 2 Kubernetes pods on 1 GKE node sharing a read-only GCE Persistent Disk

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've tried running 2 Kubernetes pods on a single-node GKE cluster, sharing a read-only GCE persistent disk, but while one pod successfully runs, the other is stuck in the `ContainerCreating` state.

The container is very simple:

```
FROM debian:jessie
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do ls /mount; sleep 5; done"]
```

The deployment looks like this:

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dumpy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: dump
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: dump
        image: gcr.io/myproject/dump
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mount
          name: dump
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: dump
        gcePersistentDisk:
          pdName: my-disk
          fsType: ext4
          readOnly: true`

The failed pod reports:

```
Warning     FailedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "xxx". Could not attach GCE PD "my-disk". Timeout waiting for mount paths to be created.
FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: Could not attach GCE PD "my-disk". Timeout waiting for mount paths to be created.
```

`/var/log/kubelet.log` reports:

```
gce.go:422] GCE operation failed: googleapi: Error 400: The disk resource 'my-disk' is already being used by 'xxx-123'
gce_util.go:187] Error attaching PD "my-disk": googleapi: Error 400: The disk resource 'my-disk' is already being used by 'xxx-123'
```

I believe the [Kubernetes documentation](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk) explicitly allows this scenario.

> A feature of PD is that they can be mounted as read-only by multiple consumers simultaneously. This means that you can pre-populate a PD with your dataset and then serve it in parallel from as many pods as you need.

What's going on and what's the fix?

Comment: It's quite possible that this is just a bug in the PD code. The PD handling code has been pretty much completely rewritten for the upcoming 1.3 release of Kubernetes and is expected to be much more reliable.

Comment: Hi Robert. When is 1.3 projected to be released?

Comment: Around the end of this month. See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Release-1.3

Answer (score 2):

Glen, you're hitting https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19953

There's no good workaround for this.

It's fixed by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/26351 which will be part of the next Kubernetes release (v1.3) scheduled to be released by the end of the June (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/wiki/Release-1.3).

Comment: I also got this issue while on v1.3.4. And I wonder where's the exact best place for bugs support. UserVoice, StackOverflow, or Kubernetes GitHub?

Comment: @HendyIrawan multi-mounts on read-only GCE PDs should work on v1.3+. You can report k8s issues here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/ Or ask for help on the one of slack channels: https://kubernetes.slack.com